# OpenvSwitch port-security on physical interface

Tags: sdn, port-security, ovs

I want to secure ports on OVS and allow specific clients source MAC addresses to an interface, to improve security on my network,

Here is my scenario:

```
ovs box with 4 physical port,
port1 connected to server 1 ( MAC A )
port2 connected to server 2 ( MAC B )
port3 connected to server 3 ( MAC C )
port4 connected to server 4 ( MAC D )
```

The condition is, OVS ports only send and receive from specified MAC addresses, if MAC changed, DROP. if port1 received frames from any source than MAC A, DROP.

There is a port-security option, but only for logical ports assigned to  logical switches, not for physical ports, source: "lsp-set-port-security" section on http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovn-nbctl.8.html

Is there any IF NOT condition on ovs-ofctl add-flow command?